# Saving audio clip in HoloLens app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, hololens

In my holographic app I am using TextToSpeechManager from HoloToolkit to generate an audio clip.

https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Utilities/Scripts/TextToSpeechManager.cs

As you can see we have a reference to the audio clip variable in line number 302. I want to save this audio clip as a wav or mp3 file in assets folder. I tried SavWav but it does not work in this case for some reason. Is there any other way to do it?

Edit: It does not work by saving the file using persistentDataPath as well

Edit2: I have added a single line after line 302 in TextToSpeechManager.cs which can be found in the above link.

`audioSource.clip = clip;
SavWav.Save(Application.persistentDataPath +"/myfile", clip);`

Comment: You are not supposed to save in Asset folder since this folder does not exist in th ebuild. You save in persistentDataPath or specific folder created for the app.

Comment: Even when I do this :

SavWav.Save(Application.persistentDataPath +"/myfile", clip); I cannot find the saved audioclip anywhere in the App. Where can I find the saved files?

Comment: Please show your save and load code in your question.

Comment: Done..I dont need to load the clip as it is generated internally in TextToSpeechManager

Comment: You said it's not saving...How do you know this? Use `File.Exists` and `File.ReadAllBytes` to check if the file is there after saving it.